# How to get Current Stdout from process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will run a console app which is a .exe file, poll the stdout from the .exe, and depending on what get's printed to the console, will invoke a key-stroke or exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) the application. I want to be able to read the console output while the process is still running. So I don't want to wait until the process is complete.

Initially, I tried to accomplish this by creating a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object and calling `.Start()` on that process and then getting the `.StandardOutput` from that object. But that looks like it waits until the process is complete as I have tested the `ping` command.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28440479/291709

Comment: Agree. You'll need to expand the `-Action` script block for what happens when StdOut or StdErr events are detected, but otherwise that answer is the approach I'd try.