# Command is running fine in console but not when used by Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, deployment, ssis

I have a PS script that should deploy a project to my SSIS server.
When I run the generated command in a console it runs fine but when the command is executed from Powershell it fails because of this (windows) error :

> **TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services**
>
> The path format is invalid.
>   Parameter name: DestinationPath (ISDeploymentWizard)
>
> **ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**
>
> The path format is invalid. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common)

If I run the generated command from a console it runs fine:

```
D:\Deploy\ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:"D:\Deploy\Receive\My_Beautiful_Project.ispac" /DestinationServer:"localhost" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/My Beautiful Project/My_Beautiful_Project" /ProjectPassword:"SuperSecretPassword"
```

The script (thanks to suggestions from Guenther Schmitz and Janne Tukaanen) :

```
#region script configuration
$SsisServer = "."
$ProjectFileFolder = "D:\Deploy\Receive"
$ProjectFileName = "My_Beautiful_Project.ispac"
$ProjectFilePassword = "SuperSecretPassword"
$FolderName = "My Beautiful Project"
$ProjectName = "My_Beautiful_Project"
$ISDeploymentWizard = "D:\Deploy\ISDeploymentWizard.exe"
#endregion

#region project deployment
# Create command line arguments
$DestinationPath = "/SSISDB/" + $FolderName + "/" + $ProjectName
$ProjectFilePath = $ProjectFileFolder + "\" + $ProjectFileName
$cmd = $ISDeploymentWizard
$arg1 = "/Silent"
$arg1a= "/ModelType:Project"
$arg2 = "/SourcePath:""$ProjectFilePath"""
$arg3 = "/DestinationServer:""$SsisServer"""
$arg4 = "/DestinationPath:""$DestinationPath"""
$arg5 = "/ProjectPassword:""$ProjectFilePassword"""
Write-Host "$cmd" $arg1 $arg1a $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
& "$cmd" $arg1 $arg1a $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5


Write-Host "Done"
#endregion
```

Comment: Isn't `$cmd` missing from you execution line? You are trying to run `$arg1` now.

Comment: It was indeed. But now I have a different error :| (see question)

Comment: replace all the curly 'smart' quotes with straight ones

Comment: That is formatting due to stackoverflow :|

Comment: did you try the pure powershell solution? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-powershell?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Good Guenther! Thanx!

Comment: The thing is: the package is secured with a password (EncryptSensitiveWithPassword). I can't find how to implement that in the powershell solution?

Comment: Apparently DeployProject($ProjectName, $projectFile) has no way to set the password.  So I need to get this to work...

Comment: This is would store your password in a file `(get-credential).password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | set-content 'C:\your_path\password.txt'`

Comment: To see what has gone wrong just look at a command line of the process (using Windows' Task Manager or Process Explorer) when it shows you the error and compare it with the working command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to declare the following variables `$arg1 $arg1a $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5`, just run the following command *(why declaring variables and storing their values in another variables??)*:

```
& $cmd /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:$ProjectFilePath /DestinationServer:$SsisServer /DestinationPath:$DestinationPath /ProjectPassword:$ProjectFilePassword
```

Comment: This did it! Now the deploy runs.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the executable in the line below `Write-Host`.

change

```
& $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

to

```
& $cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

Comment: I did that. I also noticed that the string provided when I manually run ISDeploymentWizard has an extra parameter. I added that also. But when I run it now I get a different error (updated question)

Answer (score 1):

If you have troubles to start console apps in powershell (typically because of multiple arguments), you may execute it through cmd (in powershell)

```
cmd /c "$cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5"
```

There is also another option using Process class, so you don't have to use cmd:

```
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "D:\Deploy\ISDeploymentWizard.exe"
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "$arg1 $arg1a $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5"
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false 
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 

$Process.Start() | Out-Null 
$output = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
$errors = $Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$Process.WaitForExit() 
Write-Host $output 
Write-Error $errors
```

You can check this for some more details:
 [PowerShell, stream Process output and errors while running external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239127/powershell-stream-process-output-and-errors-while-running-external-process)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still fails on the Destinationpath. I tried a destinationpath without spaces but it gives me the same error. So it seems not to be the content of destinationpath  that causes the error.

Comment: Strange. Can you just copy a working command from console  (without string building). Like cmd /c  'working command here' Also try to use single quotes, sometimes it matters

Comment: Also check this link, it uses slightly diffferent approach for that (for PS) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555086/how-to-deploy-a-existing-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /ModelType:Project /SourcePath:”D:\Deploy\Receive\My_Beautiful_Project.ispac.ispac” /DestinationServer:”.” /DestinationPath:”/SSISDB/My Beautiful Project/My_Beautiful_Project” /ProjectPassword:”SuperSecretPassword”

Comment: I looked at that but couldn't find how to include the password

Comment: Try to remove spaces from destination folder (somebody mentioned that might be an issue). I think you can also save your working cmd command as a bat file, and just call it from powershell (by typing full  path to that bat)

Comment: The spaces were not the issue, I tested that. The latter woyuld have been a solution too I think but the following turmed out to be the answer:

There is no need to declare the following variables $arg1 $arg1a $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5, just run the following command

Comment: Just realized there is another approach for that, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that the `$DestinationPath` needs to be a non relative path. Change it to the full path including the drive and I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: DestinationPath is the destinationpath within the SSIS catalog. I do not think there is a drive involved?